# Create a top bar navigation from an Array in React native

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I have an array of menu like

```
const menu = ['A','B','C']
```

And I want to render it inside a `materialTopTabNavigation`. Since the last update it is not possible to use the function `createmateriaTopTabNavigation` and pass parameters to it, the only option is to render it as a component.

The only option available is:

```
     const TopTab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();

    <TopTab.Navigator tabBarOptions={
      {
        activeTintColor:'#fff',
        scrollEnabled:true,
        indicatorStyle: {
          backgroundColor:'#fff'
        },
        style: {
          backgroundColor:'#6930c3'
        }
      }
    }>
      <TopTab.Screen name="tout" component={TabChild} />
      <TopTab.Screen name="hotellerie" component={TabChild} />
      <TopTab.Screen name="restauration" component={TabChild} />
      <TopTab.Screen name="spa" component={TabChild} />

    </TopTab.Navigator>
```

Which is not dynamic at all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am using a similar approach in one of my RN projects like this by using a simple `map` implementation and use its outcome as a child of Navigator component:

```
import { createMaterialTopTabNavigator } from '@react-navigation/material-top-tabs';

const menu = ['A', 'B', 'C'];

const TopTab = createMaterialTopTabNavigator();


const MainComponent = () => {
  const tabs = menu.map(menuItem => <TopTab.Screen name={menuItem} component={TabChild} />);

  return (
    <TopTab.Navigator tabBarOptions={
          {
            activeTintColor: '#fff',
            scrollEnabled: true,
            indicatorStyle: {
              backgroundColor: '#fff',
            },
            style: {
              backgroundColor: '#6930c3',
            },
          }
        }
    >
      {tabs}
    </TopTab.Navigator>
  );
};
```

package.json

```
"react-navigation": "^4.4.0",
"@react-navigation/material-top-tabs" : "^5.3.0"
```

Comment: Error: Couldn't find any screens for the navigator. Have you defined any screens as its children?

Comment: what version of react-navigation are you using? and how do you import createMaterialTopTabNavigator?

Comment: "@react-navigation/material-bottom-tabs": "^5.2.16",
    "@react-navigation/material-top-tabs": "^5.2.19",
    "@react-navigation/native": "^5.7.3",
    "@react-navigation/stack": "^5.9.0",

Comment: for the sake of testing, can you try to use createBottomTabNavigator instead of createMaterialTopTabNavigator? using @react-navigation/bottom-tabs?

Comment: I found the solution it was because of the state. Your solution is working :) . Thank you !

Comment: Can you write a code of TabChild component? Because I have a project related with Array